# How to make the ToolTip appear in the foreground of the floating CPaneDialog?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

Does anybody has a hint for the following problem?

I have a derived class from CPaneDialog, it contains just one button. I want to show a tooltip if the mouse is over it. For this I use CMFCToolTipCtrl:

```
// Create the ToolTip control.
m_ToolTip.Create(this, TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_NOPREFIX);
m_ToolTip.Activate(TRUE);

CMFCToolTipInfo params;
params.m_bVislManagerTheme = TRUE;

m_ToolTip.SetParams(&params);
m_ToolTip.AddTool(GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1), _T("Here is the text of my tooltip message."));
```

The m_ToolTip.RelayEvent(pMsg) I call from PreTranslateMessage().

If i compile and run the application, it looks like on the image below: The tooltip appears in the background of my pane!

[ToolTipOnPane http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9926/tooltiponpanedialog.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9926/tooltiponpanedialog.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the topmost property.

```
m_ToolTip.SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```